# Postgresql super slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
2015-04-13 07:24:12 CEST LOG:  duration: 21427.285 ms  plan:
Query Text: UPDATE "User" set last_stick=NOW() where id=2;
Update on "User"  (cost=0.00..2.03 rows=1 width=286) (actual time=21427.282..21427.282 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on "User"  (cost=0.00..2.03 rows=1 width=286) (actual time=0.020..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (id = 2)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
```

between 300ms and 32 seconds to update one row in a table which contains 2 rows. (seems to be totally random, and the system is idle during the update.). Is there any useful tip or tool I can use to spy what the hell is postgres doing or waiting for...

NB: postgres is on a x64 windows env

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Is `last_stick` indexed? Did you try to disable you anti-virus for the Postgres data directory? What kind of harddisk is that? (btw: avoid quoted identifiers - they are much more trouble than they are worth it)

Comment: I like the antivirus tip i'll try ! The system is super fast and the db is on a seagate raptor HDD... I solved my problem by modifying a script which was connected on the DB (without understanding exactly why it was slowing that much), but i'll take any advice to debug such a situation just in case it happends again...

Comment: "*by modifying a script which was connected on the DB*" and what script was that? And what exactly did you change?

Comment: The script opened two conections, one which listen (with the pgsql LISTEN function), the other to do some light computing. Now i'm using only one connection and the DB is running well again. I believe it's a strange behaviour of PHP postgresql driver... However, it would be cool if postgres had a verbose mode for the queries to know what he is exactly doing... (I know about EXPLAIN, but that is not what i'm searching for.)

Comment: Any concurrent sessions? I'd guess locking was involved. If you're on 9.4 enable `log_lock_waits`.

Comment: Cool that is something very useful, ty. But it should normally not be the problem. One session was only to listen, and never access the data.